# Beam WriteToBigQuery Python class fails and doesn't log useful information

Tags: python, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

This is my usage

```
def write_to_bigquery(args):
    dictionary_rows = "Create Linked Dictionary" >> beam.Map(
        _translate_matched_series_to_dict
    )
    return dictionary_rows | "Write to BigQuery" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
        args.output_table,
        schema=_get_table_schema(),
        write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
        create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
        custom_gcs_temp_location=f"gs://{args.temp_storage_bucket}",
    )
```

schema is like that:
`[{"name": field.name, "type": type_str, "mode": "NULLABLE"}, ...much more fiels, ]`

It's failing to insert in the table with the error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery_tools.py", line 637, in wait_for_bq_job
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: BigQuery job beam_bq_job_LOAD_alminoralllinkagetest20230501_LOAD_STEP_818_e472c3092b9a929012fe506ee87f1d12_01b64c3e2a604526a0fcfd0f18ec05f5 failed. Error Result: <ErrorProto
 location: 'gs://some_url_A'
 message: 'Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 6830; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details. File: 'gs://some_url_A'
 reason: 'invalid'> [while running 'Create Linked Dictionary|Write to BigQuery/Write to BigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/TriggerLoadJobsWithoutTempTables/ParDo(TriggerLoadJobs)-ptransform-70']
```

The file indicated seeing the errors just shows the content that tried to be inserted, not the error log, so I can't understand what's the problem.

Comment: Useful? https://medium.com/google-cloud/error-handling-with-apache-beam-presentation-of-asgarde-ce5e5dfb2d74

Comment: In my experience this is due to the fact, that your data does not match with the schema of the table. However, too many fields where affected for a useful error message (i.e., probably more than one, or multiple rows of data). I would recommend double checking the data with your schema (in particular check for whitespaces in the column names)